# Best way of querying table without providing the primary key

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I am designing  the data model of our Scylla database. For example, I created a table, intraday_history, with fields:

`CREATE TABLE intraday_history (id bigint,timestamp_seconds bigint,timestamp timestamp,sec_code text,open float,high float,low float,close float,volume float,trade int, PRIMARY KEY ((id,sec_code),timestamp_seconds,timestamp));`

My id is a twitter_snowflake generated 64-bit integers.. My problem is how can I use WHERE without providing always the id (most of the time I will use the timestamp with bigint). I also encounter this problem in other tables. Because the id is unique then I cannot query a batch of timestamp.

Is it okay if lets say for a bunch of tables for my 1 node, I will use an ID like `cluster1` so that when I query the id I will just id=cluster1 ? But it loss the uniqueness feature

`Allow filtering` comes as an option here. But I keep reading that it is a bad practice, especially when dealing with millions of query.

I'm using the ScyllaDB, a compatible c++ version of Apache Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra, as you've probably already read, the queries derive the tables, not the other way around. So your situation where you want to query by a different filter would ideally entail you creating another Cassandra table. That's the optimal way. Partition keys are required in filters unless you provide the "allow filtering" "switch", but it isn't recommended as it will perform a DC (possibly cluster)-wide search, and you're still subjected to timeouts. You could consider using indexes or materialized views, which are basically cassandra maintained tables populated by the base table's changes. That would save you the troubles of having the application populate multiple tables (Cassandra would do it for you). We've had some luck with materialized views, but with either of these components, there can be side effects like any other cassandra table (inconsistencies, latencies, additional rules, etc.). I would say do a bit of research to  determine the best approach, but most likely providing "allow filtering" isn't the best choice (especially for high volume and frequent queries or with tables containing high volumes of data). You could also investigate SOLR if that's an option, depending on what you're filtering.

Hope that helps.

-Jim

Comment: I was using this guide, https://dzone.com/articles/best-practices-for-cassandra-data-modeling . What I do is I group more common column variable with certain types as partition keys to evenly distribute